# Use two or more instances of a single message driven bean to read two MQ:s

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, mq, message-driven-bean

I have a requirement of splitting messages that are currently in one IBM MQ (read by an MDB on WLS) in to two separate MQ:s based on the type of the message.

One type is "batch messages" where the message creators might issue batches of tens of thousands of messages at a time.

Another type is "online messages" which are generated one at the time and need to be processed immediately.

Problem is that currently if an online message is placed to the queue right after a batch delivery it will take too long before it will be processed. Message priority in MQ might be an appropriate solution but due to some MQ infra issues which are out of my hands it cant be used.

Actual question is that is it possible to use the same MDB to read both queues by creating two instances which read the separate queues? Message content would be the same in both queues and I was hoping this could be solved by configuration rather than building and deploying two MDB:s with different properties. And just to clarify it's the lovely EJB 2.1. Updating to 3.x is an option if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886189/configuring-an-mdb-to-listen-to-multiple-queues

Comment: You and your colleages can use PRIORITY in MQ.
Online and batch applications write with different priority.
Additionally the mq admin has to change the queue attribute 'Message delivery sequence' from FIFO to PRIORITY