# Configuring 1 MDB to listen to 2 queues in Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, ejb

I have an MDB that is listening to 1 Queue configured using ActivationSpecification in WAS. Now I have to configure the same MDB to listen to another Queue in same ApplicationServer. I know how to define another Queue in my ibm-ejb-jar-bnd-xmi and add it to the MDB in eclipse . 
I am lost on how to add the ActivationSpecification of the 2nd Queue to the Configuration in WAS . These configurations are given at the of deploying the EJB in WAS and are the Binding Info on the Listeners for Message Driven Beans.

Since I already have the bind for 1 queue I am lost on how to give the bind for the 2nd queue???

Please advise .

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886189/configuring-an-mdb-to-listen-to-multiple-queues